# Cucumber-jvm feature file and step definition file implementation issue

Tags: java, git, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

I am new to Cucumber framework, and designed one selenium maven project using Cucumber framework.
But I am struggling to get rid of an issue for last one week , I have explored all possible solutions on internet. eg. putting runner and step definition file under src/test dir and feature file under test/resources dir ..and many thing, I tried everything possible from my end but nothing could help me.
I have shared the [git hub link](https://github.com/GarimaKoushik/com.CRM.cucumber.git) at the bottom.
Here is the issue I am getting -

-----------------------**issue/error** ---------------------------------------------

1 Scenarios (�[33m1 undefined�[0m)
3 Steps (�[33m3 undefined�[0m)
0m0.000s

You can implement missing steps with the snippets below:

```
    @given("^User is already on login page$")
    public void user_is_already_on_login_page() throws Throwable {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new PendingException();
   }

 @when("^title of login page is Free CRM$")
   public void title_of_login_page_is_Free_CRM() throws Throwable {
   // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
   throw new PendingException();
}

@then("^user enters username and password$")
public void user_enters_username_and_password() throws Throwable {
// Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
throw new PendingException();
}
```

---

**project available on git hub -**

https://github.com/GarimaKoushik/com.CRM.cucumber.git

Comment: Have you tried with the setting glue="stepDefinition". Maven will automatically pick up the tests under the src\test folder, so if using maven for execution that would be a better option.

Comment: Check my updated answer

Answer (score 2):

Based on your code of TestRunner class: You need to add package name inside glue attribute. `stepDefinition` and please put your feature file inside folder, not in any package.

You can refer this link :- http://toolsqa.com/cucumber/cucumber-options/

Please try below code

```
package Runner;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features= "src/main/java/Features/",
        glue= {"stepDefinition"},
        monochrome=false

        )

public class TestRunner {

}
```

Comment: Please accept my answers so other can also get help from it